# Laravel/Ajax: Form remove current class in save and add another class depending on button clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

I have two ajax functions with different effects, both are trying to use one button (Save) within a modal

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_group', function(e) {(content here) });
$(document).on('click', '.update_group', function(e) { (content here) });
```

here in the screenshot, "New Routing Group" uses `add_group` and "Edit" uses `update_group`
[image: 1]

here is the modal involved:

[image: 2]

This is the save button they are targeting

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block add_group"></i>Save</button>
```

By default the save button is using `add_group`.

Looking for advice. In my situation, how do I use `.removeClass` and `.addClass`? Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: As both have different event handler you can simply use `$(".btn-block").removeClass("update_group").addClass("add_group")` and same for other event handler just reverse the classes.

Comment: thanks for the tip, still trying to figure out this because remove class is not working as intended